# makefile variable automatically assignment with index

Tags: makefile

I have a question about variable assignments in makefile.
given 2 lists of the same size as below :
(there are no any characters or string match between 2 lists)

```
index := 1 2 3 4 5
objects := one_obj two_obj three_obj four_obj five_obj
```

and I need some index to be active, for example, 1 and 3

```
act_idx := 1 3

all :
    @echo act_obj = $(act_obj)
```

how should I assign $(act_obj) to get the output as "act_obj = one_obj three_obj" after I type "make all" in shell ?

Comment: There ought to be a name for the problem with this question; there is no way to know how much of the regularity in the example we are allowed to exploit. In this case, `act_obj := $(addsuffix _obj, $(act_idx))` will do, but perhaps you *meant* the more general question: given two lists of the same size, and a selection from the first list, how to construct the corresponding selection from the second list.

Comment: thanks for your comment! maybe I should rewrite my question and actually it is more close to what you mentioned above.

Comment: @Beta In fact, [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-selectcol-nrstablewhere-clause) was originally written for this exact purpose and implements a modest `select` from tabled data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNUmake library at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt was originally written with this exact use case in mind (it grew into a everything-but-the-kitchen-sink, but oh well).

The formulation for the selection process which you are basically needing here is done with the relational table idiom. You produce a table as GNUmake string list and execute a select statement which mimicks a simple SQL select.

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

# define a table with 2 columns (no empty cells allowed!)
define object_tbl :=
2
key1 one_obj
key2 two_obj
key3 three_obj
key4 four_obj
key5 five_obj
endef

act_keys := key1 key3

# SELECT column 2 FROM object_tbl WHERE column 1 is found in act_keys
objects := $(call select,2,$(object_tbl),$$(filter $$1,$(act_keys)))

$(info $(objects))
```

Output:

```
one_obj three_obj
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

More complex clauses (using arithmetic e.g.) are also possible.

Comment: gmtt is really a powerful toolkit for makefile. I learned a lot from your sharing and thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
act_obj := $(foreach I,$(act_idx),$(filter $I_%,$(objects)))
```

Based on the adjusted question you can do something like this:

```
act_obj := $(foreach I,$(act_idx),$(word $I,$(objects)))
```

You can probably work this out yourself from the [set of functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html) described in the GNU make manual.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I have renewed my question. Are there  solutions if there exist no any characters or string match between the 2 variable lists ?